# Explain the idea behind of consistent nonlocking reads in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've just read a mysql docs where I found such sentence: "A consistent read means that InnoDB uses multi-versioning to present **to a query** a snapshot of the database at a point in time."

I read a lot of mysql doc pages, but still cann't clarify to myself what exactly "to a query" here means. Definitly it ralates to a SELECT statement, but what about if my transaction starts with UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE statement?

Thanks!

Comment: When it says query, it means everything that is considered a query. Query is not just SELECT, it's DELETE / UPDATE / INSERT as well.

Comment: Very, very big thanks to you, bro!

Answer (score 2):

I found another way on my answer. And I think it should be apripriate by the others. So, days of searching whiting oracle docs and finaly founed:

InnoDB creates a consistent read view or a consistent snapshot either when the statement

mysql> START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT;

is executed or when the first select query is executed in the transaction.

https://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlinnodb/entry/repeatable_read_isolation_level_in

Comment: I think it's important to understand that no consistent shapshots will be assigned to a transaction untill you implicitly add WITH CONSISTENT SNAPHOT after START TRANSACTION as in example above. It means that if you write multiple UPDATE statements for example without this "magic" your transaction snapshot will be refreshed every time. Even in a such small understanding appers a way to improve perfomance of queries...(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html)

Answer (score 0):

When the query can change the data, the database also uses locks to synchronise queries.

So between queries that change data, locks are used to make sure that only one query at a time can change specific items. Between a query that reads data and a query that changes data, multi-versioning is used to present the data before the change to the query that reads it.